# Whats the difference between Keyboard.Focus(item) and item.Focus()?

Tags: .net, wpf

In WPF, there are two ways to set the focus to an element.
You can either call the .Focus() method of the input element, or call Keyboard.Focus() with the input element as parameter.

```
// first way:
item.Focus();
// alternate way:
Keyboard.Focus(item);
```

What is the difference between these two? Are there special reasons to use one of them instead of the other in some cases?
So far I noticed no difference - what ever method I used, the item always got logical focus as well as keyboard focus.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the first things that `item.Focus()` does is call `Keyboard.Focus( this )`. If that fails, then it makes calls to `FocusManager`, as decasteljau has answered.

The following are copied from disassambler view in [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/).

This is from `UIElement` (`UIElement3D` is the same):

```
public bool Focus()
{
    if (Keyboard.Focus(this) == this)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (this.Focusable && this.IsEnabled)
    {
        DependencyObject focusScope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(this);
        if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(focusScope) == null)
        {
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(focusScope, this);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is from `ContentElement`:

```
public bool Focus()
{
    return (Keyboard.Focus(this) == this);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As per [WPF documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx):

> In WPF there are two main concepts that pertain to focus: keyboard focus and logical focus. Keyboard focus refers to the element that receives keyboard input and logical focus refers to the element in a focus scope that has focus.

and

> An element that has keyboard focus will also have logical focus, but an element that has logical focus does not necessarily have keyboard focus.

Comment: So it would be better to use Keyboard.Focus()? Strange, though, when I used item.Focus() the keyboard focus always had been on the item, too.

Comment: The others said pretty much the same thing as I did, just with code samples (yay!). Dunno why this was down voted...

Comment: I don't get the downvote, either. The difference between logical and keyboard focus is good info.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may want to know that item.Focus() is the equivalent of calling:

```
DependencyObject focusScope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(item);
if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(focusScope) == null)
{
   FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(focusScope, item);
}
```

Comment: `setFocusedElement` is only setting logical focus. `Focus()` may do both keyboard and logical