# Can't set focus to a child of UserControl

Tags: wpf, focus, user-controls, focusmanager

I have a `UserControl` which contains a `TextBox`.  When my main window loads I want to set the focus to this textbox so I added `Focusable="True" GotFocus="UC_GotFocus"` to the `UserControl`s definition and `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=login}"` to my main windows definition.  In the `UC_GotFocus` method i simply call `.Focus()` on the control i want to focus on but this doesn't work.

All i need to do is have a `TextBox` in a `UserControl` receive focus when the application starts.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I recently fixed this problem for a login splash screen that is being displayed via a storyboard when the main window is first loaded.

I believe there were two keys to the fix.  One was to make the containing element a focus scope.   The other was to handle the Storyboard Completed event for the storyboard that was triggered by the window being loaded.

This storyboard makes the username and password canvas visible and then fades into being 100% opaque.  The key is that the username control was not visible until the storyboard ran and therefore that control could not get **keyboard** focus until it was visible.  What threw me off for awhile was that it had "focus" (i.e. focus was true, but as it turns out this was only logical focus) and I did not know that WPF had the concept of both logical and keyboard focus until reading Kent Boogaart's answer and looking at Microsoft's WPF [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx)

Once I did that the solution for my particular problem was straightforward:

1) Make the containing element a focus scope

```
<Canvas FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBox x:Name="m_uxUsername" AcceptsTab="False" AcceptsReturn="False">
    </TextBox>
</Canvas>
```

2) Attach a Completed Event Handler to the Storyboard

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="Splash Screen" Completed="UserNamePassword_Storyboard_Completed">
...
</Storyboard>
```

and

3) Set my username TextBox to have the keyboard focus in the storyboard completed event handler.

```
void UserNamePassword_Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 m_uxUsername.Focus();
}
```

Note that calling item.Focus() results in the call Keyboard.Focus(this), so you don't need to call this explicitly.  See this question about the [difference between Keyboard.Focus(item) and item.Focus.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197088/whats-the-difference-between-keyboard-focusitem-and-item-focus)

Comment: Thanks! In my particular case involving a UserControl with a TextBox inside needing initial focus, I used the UserControl's Loaded event and entered textBox.Focus();. I didn't need the first step (IsFocusScope=true).

Answer (score 18):

Its stupid but it works:

Pop a thread that waits a while then comes back and sets the focus you want.  It even works within the context of an element host.

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

 System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                   (a) =>
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                            someUiElementThatWantsFocus.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            new Action(() =>
                            {
                                someUiElementThatWantsFocus.Focus();

                            }));
                        }
                   );

}
```

Comment: I agree this is not something I like to use, but the most robust mechanism I found so far. There are some circumstances where uiElement.Focus() returns false, race conditions, CommandBindings etc. If all I know is, that in the end I should be able to Focus, then I have indeed used this now, because it's too time consuming to try all other methods at runtime (unit tests are hard to write for this). Still I wouldn't recommend it as a best-practice, but rahter ultima ratio.

Comment: hey man, I have stolen your solution and used it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520945/textbox-embedded-in-a-listbox-initial-focus hope you don't mind :D

Comment: Works great and is a simple answer

Comment: Reviving an old solution but I just had this problem recently and this is what worked for me

Comment: The only thing that helped me. After trying 4 other top solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Just recently I had a list-box that housed some TextBlocks. I wanted to be able to double click on the text block and have it turn into a TextBox, then focus on it and select all the text so the user could just start typing the new name (Akin to Adobe Layers)

Anyway, I was doing this with an event and it just wasn't working. The magic bullet for me here was making sure that I set the event to handled. I figure it *was* setting focus, but as soon as the event went down the path it was switching the logical focus.

The moral of the story is, make sure you're marking the event as handled, that might be your issue.

Comment: Thanks, this tip got me out of my jamb. Mark the mouse down event as handled! I was calling this.Focus() in my user control's mouse down event. I was seeing GotFocus fire, followed immediately by LostFocus, with the focus going to my user control's parent.  Reason? I wasn't marking the mouse down event has handled, so I guess the parent control was taking focus away from me as part of continuing to process the mouse down event after me!

Answer (score 7):

> “When setting initial focus at application startup, the element to
> receive focus must be connected to a PresentationSource and the
> element must have Focusable and IsVisible set to true. The recommended
> place to set initial focus is in the Loaded event handler"

(MSDN)

Simply add a "Loaded" event handler in the constructor of your Window (or Control), and in that event handler call the Focus() method on the target control.

```
    public MyWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        textBox.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

since i tried a fuzquat's solution and found it the most generic one, i thought i'd share a different version, since some complained about it looking messy. so here it is:

```
                casted.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<UIElement>(x =>
                {
                    x.Focus();
                }), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, casted);
```

no Thread.Sleep, no ThreadPool. Clean enough i  hope.

UPDATE:

Since people seem to like pretty code:

```
public static class WpfExtensions
{
    public static void BeginInvoke<T>(this T element, Action<T> action, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle) where T : UIElement
    {
        element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(priority, action);
    }
}
```

now you can call it like this:

```
child.BeginInvoke(d => d.Focus());
```

Answer (score 3):

WPF supports two different flavors of focus:

1. Keyboard focus
2. Logical focus

The `FocusedElement` property gets or sets logical focus within a focus scope. I suspect your `TextBox` *does* have logical focus, but its containing focus scope is not the active focus scope. Ergo, it *does not* have keyboard focus.

So the question is, do you have multiple focus scopes in your visual tree?

Comment: Hmmm, i know nothing of Focus Scopes.  Time for some research!  cheers Kent.

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought I read somewhere that UserControls have their own implicit FocusScope. Perhaps if this is true then the answer to whether the original poster has multiple focus scopes in their visual tree is obviously YES!.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set your user control to `Focusable="True"` (XAML)
2. Handle the `GotFocus` event on your control and call `yourTextBox.Focus()`
3. Handle the `Loaded` event on your window and call `yourControl.Focus()`

I have a sample app running with this solution as I type. If this does not work for you, there must be something specific to your app or environment that causes the problem. In your original question, I think the binding is causing the problem.
I hope this helps.

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that after switching back from another window focus will be put onto the yourTextBox even if it wasn't there before switch

Answer (score 3):

I found a good series of blog posts on WPF focus.

- [Part 1: It’s Basically Focus](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/part-1-its-basically-focus/)
- [Part 2: Changing WPF focus in code](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/part-2-changing-wpf-focus-in-code/)
- [Part 3: Shifting focus to the first available element in WPF](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/part-3-shifting-focus-to-the-first-available-element-in-wpf/)

They are all good to read, but the 3rd part specifically deals with setting focus to a UI element in a UserControl.

Comment: Please cleanup, all links are dead.

Comment: That guy's blog seems to have vanished. I did some googling and couldn't find if it had moved somewhere. Sorry! It's been almost 10 years since I answered that questions!

Answer (score 2):

After having a 'WPF Initial Focus Nightmare' and based on some answers on stack, the following proved for me to be the best solution.

First, add your App.xaml OnStartup() the followings:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.LoadedEvent,
          new RoutedEventHandler(WindowLoaded));
```

Then add the 'WindowLoaded' event also in App.xaml :

```
void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = e.Source as Window;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        window.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        new Action(() =>
        {
            window.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));

        }));
    }
```

The threading issue must be use as WPF initial focus mostly fails due to some framework race conditions.

I found the following solution best as it is used globally for the whole app.

Hope it helps...

Oran

Answer (score 2):

What did the trick for me was the **FocusManager.FocusedElement** attribute. I first tried to set it on the UserControl, but it didn't work.

So I tried putting it on the UserControl's first child instead:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"/>
</Grid>
```

... and it worked! :)

Comment: Worked for me! That seems to be the crucial point, declaring the FocusedElement in the first child of the usercontrol. Placed the usercontrol inside a WPF elementhost.

Answer (score 2):

I converted fuzquat's answer to an extension method. I'm using this instead of Focus() where Focus() did not work.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace YourProject.Extensions
{
    public static class UIElementExtension
    {
        public static void WaitAndFocus(this UIElement element, int ms = 100)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(ms);

                element.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    element.Focus();
                }));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a focus issue specifically related to hosting WPF UserControls within ElementHosts which are contained within a Form that is set as an MDI child via the MdiParent property.

I'm not sure if this is the same issue others are experiencing but you dig into the details by following the link below.

[Issue with setting focus within a WPF UserControl hosted within an ElementHost in a WindowsForms child MDI form](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7d41218e-c2bb-4957-b0b4-aa24efc4d8c2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like solutions with setting another tab scope for UserControl. In that case, you will have two different carets when navigating by keyboard: on the window and the another - inside user control. My solution is simply to redirect focus from user control to inner child control. Set user control focusable (because by default its false):

```
<UserControl ..... Focusable="True">
```

and override focus events handlers in code-behind:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
    MyTextBox.Focus();
}

protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);
    Keyboard.Focus(MyTextBox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have user control - stack panel with two text boxes.The text boxes were added in contructor, not in the xaml. When i try to focus first text box, nothing happend.
The siggestion with Loaded event fix my problem. Just called control.Focus() in Loaded event and everthing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to set focus for Username textbox, thus user can type in directly every time it shows up.

In Constructor of your control:

```
this.Loaded += (sender, e) => Keyboard.Focus(txtUsername);
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying combinations of the suggestions above, I was able to reliably assign focus to a desired text box on a child UserControl with the following.  Basically, give focus to the child control and have the child UserControl give focus to its TextBox.  The TextBox's focus statement returned true by itself, however did not yield the desired result until the UserControl was given focus as well.  I should also note that the UserControl was unable to request focus for itself and had to be given by the Window.

For brevity I left out registering the Loaded events on the Window and UserControl.

Window

```
private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ControlXYZ.Focus();
}
```

UserControl

```
private void OnControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxXYZ.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set it in the PageLoaded() or control loaded, but then I'm calling WCF async service and doing stuff that seems to lose the focus.  I have to to set it at the end of all the stuff I do.  That's fine and all, but sometimes I make changes to the code and then I forget that I'm also setting the cursor.

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem with setting keyboard focus to canvas in WPF user control.
My solution

1. In XAML set element to `Focusable="True"`
2. In `element_mousemove` event create simple check:

   ```
   if(!element.IsKeyBoardFocused)
       element.Focus();
   ```

In my case it works fine.