# wpf problem with setting focus

Tags: c#, wpf, events, focus, setfocus

Hi
I'm not able to set focus on parent of control. I have a control which is placed on canvas.
If I click that control I need to set focus on canvas in order to handle some keyboard events.
However despite the fact that I was trying to set focus like that

```
 protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
           Canvas designer = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as Canvas;
          designer.Focus() ;//this doesn't work
           Keyboard.Focus(designer); //this also doesn't work


        }
```

Keyboard events which are attached to canvas don't fire.

Comment: What happens if you move the base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e) call down below the rest of the call?

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that the Canvas has [Focusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) and [IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) both set to true.  Without that, [Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) will fail.  From [Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) docs:

> To be focusable, Focusable and IsEnabled must both be true.

In addition, since you're doing this in a PreviewMouseDown event, you may need to rework your method as follows:

```
 protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     Canvas designer = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as Canvas;
     designer.Focus() ;//this doesn't work
     Keyboard.Focus(designer); //this also doesn't work

     // Just in case something else is changing your focus as a result of a mouse event...
     e.Handled = true;
     base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
 }
```

Comment: I set these properties to true but my events still do not fire. I override method OnGotFocus to see if this event fires and OnGotFocus fires. However keyboards event don't

Comment: @george: Is Focus() returning true?

Comment: Sorry OnGotFocus event doesn't fire. EDIT Sometimes OnGotFocus is fired and sometimes is not

Comment: Works fine :) Could You tell me why you call base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e); as last method ?

Comment: @george: You can do it first, if you want.  I typically want my code to run prior to other handling code, but it depends on the situation.  In this case, if there's anything else subscribe to the handler that checked forcus, it would see your canvas has the focus, not the currently focused object - it might not matter, but it might, too...

Comment: Thanks again :) I spent like two hours trying to different methods to set a focus :)

Comment: @george - if Reed's answer helped you (and it certainly sounds like it did), it is customary in Stack Overflow to mark it as the answer and/or upvote it.  This will help both his rating on the site, and yours.  Just a good habit to get into, right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FocusManager to set the canvas as a focus scope.  There is a good example of how to do this here: [Can't set focus to a child of UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673536/wpf-cant-set-focus-to-a-child-of-usercontrol).

Answer (score -4):

I use My UserControl with attribute: Background="Transparent".

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this answers the question/how it works? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: I don't know why. I had read this in in another question. But I do not remember in which.