# textBox embedded in a ListBox initial focus

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, listbox, setfocus

I want to set the focus to the first ListBox item that is a textbox. I want to be able to write in it immedatelly without the necesity to click it or press any key. I try this but doesn't work:

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(new TextBox() { });
        (listBox1.Items[0] as TextBox).Focus();

    }
```

Comment: Do you get a `NullReferenceException` now?

Comment: @BalaR nop. I just can't write immedately, i need to click in the control or doble press the tab key.

Comment: Try Shown event instead of Loaded?

Comment: @voodoomsr see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673536/wpf-cant-set-focus-to-a-child-of-usercontrol/673569#673569

Answer (score 4):

it's stupid but it works only if you wait a moment, try this version:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = new TextBox() {};
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox);

            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                (a) =>
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    textBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(
                            delegate()
                            {
                                textBox.Focus();
                            }
                            ));
                }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

I was testing locally and could not fix it until I found this question and fuzquat answer in there so vote me here and him there :D

[Can't set focus to a child of UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673536/wpf-cant-set-focus-to-a-child-of-usercontrol)

Comment: WTF it works! XD...maybe in a future i'm going to try to understand it, right know I'm going to use it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case any body else has this issue. An UIElement has to be fully loaded before you can focus it. therefor this can be made very simple:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(new TextBox() { });
    var txBox = listBox1.Items[0] as TextBox;
    txBox.Loaded += (txbSender, args) => (txbSender as TextBox)?.Focus();
}
```