# Setting focus on TextBox on UserControl that is the content of a ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, focus, listboxitem

I have a `Button` on a `UserControl` that adds an item to a `ListBox` on that `UserControl`.  Let's call that control Parent.  The `ListBoxItem`s contain another `UserControl`.  Let's call that Child.  The button adds an item to the `ItemSource` of the listbox (MVVM style).

I can scroll that into view without a problem. I can set the focus to the `ListBoxItem`, but what I want is the focus to be set on the first `TextBox` of the child `UserControl`of the content of the `ListBoxItem`.  I can't seem to figure that out.  The code below sets the focus to the `ListBoxItem`, not the `UserControl` child of it or any control on it.

```vb
Private Sub bnAdd(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
   VM.AddDetail()
   MyList.ScrollIntoView(MyList.Items(MyList.Items.Count - 1))
   Dim ListBoxItem As ListBoxItem = MyList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyList.SelectedItem)
   ListBoxItem.Focus()
End Sub
```

On my child `UserControl` I used this in XAML:

```xaml
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtMyBox}"
```

Comment: Your usercontrol should expose a dependency property or public method responsible for setting focus on a textbox in it. Aside from encapsulation, that way someone changing the usercontrol at least has a reasonable chance of noticing they're about to break functionality when they move that textbox or whatever. How is the usercontrol instantiated? What does VM.AddDetail do? Does it have a reference to this usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673536/cant-set-focus-to-a-child-of-usercontrol) and most of the approaches use hooking into focus events to achieve the focus change. I want to propose another solution that is based on traversing the visual tree. Unfortunately, I can only provide you C# code, but you can use the concept to apply it in your Visual Basic code.

As far as I can see, you are using code-behind to scroll your items into view. I will build on that. Your list box has list box items and I guess you use a data template to display `UserControl`s as child items. Within these user controls there is a `TextBox` that you have assigned a name in XAML via `x:Name` or in code-behind via the `Name` property. Now, you need a helper method to traverse the visual tree and search for text boxes.

```cs
private IEnumerable<TextBox> FindTextBox(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
   // No other child controls, break
   if (dependencyObject == null)
      yield break;

   // Search children of the current control
   for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
   {
      var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

      // Check if the current item is a text box
      if (child is TextBox textBox)
         yield return textBox;

      // If we did not find a text box, search the children of this child recursively
      foreach (var childOfChild in FindTextBox(child))
         yield return childOfChild;
   }
}
```

Then we add a method that filters the enumerable of text boxes for a given name using Linq.

```cs
private TextBox FindTextBox(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string name)
{
   // Filter the list of text boxes for the right one with the specified name
   return FindTextBox(dependencyObject).SingleOrDefault(child => child.Name.Equals(name));
}
```

In your `bnAdd` handler you can take your `ListBoxItem`, search for the text box child and focus it.

```cs
var textBox = FindTextBox(listBoxItem, "MyTextBox");
textBox.Focus();
```